# MYSQL Select different records from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat, having

I am working on small school database and I need some help with selecting students that are only booked on different days in week 1 and week 2.

My table structure is like below:

```
ChildId    Day  Room  Week
=======    ===  ====  ====
  1        1     20    1
  1        2     20    1
  2        1     20    2
  3        1     20    1
  3        2     20    1
  3        1     20    2
=====     ===   ===   ===
```

I would like to get all the children that meet the following criteria:

- ONLY booked in week two (This is ChildId 2 and I can get this from the following query)

> ```
>   SELECT DISTINCT b.childid FROM booking b
>         where b.childid NOT IN (SELECT childid FROM bookingtemplate WHERE weekno = 1)
> ```

I also need

- all children in week two whose days are different then week one. That will be ChildID 3 as he is booked on Monday and Tuesday on Week 1 and on Monday on week 2.

I am unable to get the children whose days are different in both the weeks:

Thank you

Comment: Is the column Room relevant to your requirement?

Comment: @forpas No Room can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation and the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT ChildId 
FROM booking
WHERE Week IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY ChildId
HAVING MIN(Week) = 2
    OR GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Week = 1 THEN Day END ORDER BY Day) <>
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Week = 2 THEN Day END ORDER BY Day);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4cb36f4cf65d7a751e34c6035390a8b).

Comment: probably GROUP_CONCAT requires DISTINCT, if 4th row in the sample set day = 1, child3 should be excluded.

Comment: @ProGu I assume that the same ChildId does not book the same day twice.

Comment: @forpas I should have mentioned that child could be booked in two rooms for the same day(morning session and afternoon session)

Comment: @snowflakes74 I already asked for this in a comment under your question and you answered: *No Room can be ignored*

Comment: @forpas yes I did  I am sorry, now that I looked more into the data there is one child that is booked in two rooms for the same day.

Comment: @snowflakes74 then add DISTINCT inside GROUP_CONCAT(). See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you , that did it.. perfect results are being returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can self-join the table and filter the cases where days are different.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  b1.ChildId
FROM
  booking b1
INNER JOIN
  booking b2
ON
  b1.ChildId = v2.ChildId
  AND b1.Week = 1 AND b2.Week = 2
  AND b1.Day <> b2.Day
```

Comment: This does not return ChildId = 2

Comment: ChildID 2 is not on both weeks.  This is only for the latter part of the question because the OP seems to have solved the first part (childern in week 2) already.

Comment: I assume that the OP needs the results for both conditions in a single query.